# If $E(Y)=0$, $Cov(Y, E(Y|X))\geq0$ for any random variable $X$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, covariance

Let $Y$ be a random variable with mean zero and finite variance, and let $X$ be any other random variable. Using the fact that $\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$ and the law of iterated expectation, we have $$\text{Cov}(Y, 
\mathbb{E}[Y|X])=\mathbb{E}[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])(\mathbb{E}[Y|X]-\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]])]=\mathbb{E}[Y\mathbb{E}[Y|X]].$$ I am tempted to say this is the expectation of $Y^2$, which would settle the question, but I don't know how to justify it (or even if it's true in the first place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lemma below comes handy:

> **Lemma.** Assume $X$ and $Y$ are $L^1$-random variables on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbf{P})$. Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$. Then
>
> $$ \mathbf{Cov}(\mathbf{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}], Y) = \mathbf{Cov}(\mathbf{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}], \mathbf{E}[Y \mid \mathcal{G}]). $$

*Proof.* We will make use of the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) and ["pulling-out-what's-known" property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties). Also, for better readibility, we write $\color{navy}{\bar{X}} = \mathbf{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}]$ and $\color{navy}{\bar{Y}} = \mathbf{E}[Y \mid \mathcal{G}]$. Then

\begin{align*}
&\mathbf{Cov}(\color{navy}{\bar{X}}, Y) \\
&= \mathbf{E}[\color{navy}{\bar{X}}Y] - \mathbf{E}[\color{navy}{\bar{X}}]\mathbf{E}[Y] \\
&= \mathbf{E}[\mathbf{E}[\color{navy}{\bar{X}}Y \mid \mathcal{G}]] - \mathbf{E}[\color{navy}{\bar{X}}]\mathbf{E}[\mathbf{E}[Y \mid \mathcal{G}]] \tag{by LTE} \\
&= \mathbf{E}[\color{navy}{\bar{X}}\mathbf{E}[Y \mid \mathcal{G}]] - \mathbf{E}[\color{navy}{\bar{X}}]\mathbf{E}[\mathbf{E}[Y \mid \mathcal{G}]] \tag{pulling out} \\
&= \mathbf{E}[\color{navy}{\bar{X}}\color{navy}{\bar{Y}}] - \mathbf{E}[\color{navy}{\bar{X}}]\mathbf{E}[\color{navy}{\bar{Y}}] \\
&= \mathbf{Cov}(\color{navy}{\bar{X}}, \color{navy}{\bar{Y}}),
\end{align*}

completing the proof. $\square$

Returning to OP's problem, we get

$$ \mathbf{Cov}(Y, \mathbf{E}[Y \mid X])
= \mathbf{Var}(\mathbf{E}[Y \mid X])
\geq 0. $$

Note that the assumption $\mathbf{E}[Y] = 0$ is redundant here. We only need to assume that $Y$ is $L^1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(X)=E(YE(Y|X) $ then for any $A$ we have
$$\int_Af(x)\mu(dx)=E(f(X)1_{X\in A})=E(Y^2)1_{X\in  A})\geq 0$$ hence $f\geq 0 $ $\mu$ almost everywhere.